# How to establish VPC peering from a VPC (VPC A) to two other VPC (VPC B and C) having the same CIDR range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, aws-vpc-peering, aws-route-table

I have a VPC A(say 192.168.0.0/22) and VPC B and C having CIDRs 10.0.0.0/16. A VPC peering from  A to B already exists (say pcx 1). And have to establish another VPC peering from A to C (say pcx 2). In Order to do that I attached another CIDR block (10.1.0.0/16) to VPC C, and added a new peering connection from A to C (pcx 2). A public subnet with an EC2 instance exists in each of the VPCs.

In the route table of public subnet of VPC A :

- **Destination**---------**Target**
- 10.0.0.0/16   ----------  pcx 1
- 10.1.0.0/16   ----------  pcx 2

Route table public subnet of VPC B:

- **Destination** ---------- **Target**
- 192.168.0.0/22--------pcx 1

Route table public subnet of VPC C:

- **Destination** --------- **Target**
- 192.168.0.0/22--------pcx 2

The security group associated with each of the EC2 instance in VPC A allows all ICMP-IPv4 traffic from 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.1.0.0/16

Similarly EC2 in VPCs B and C, allows all ICMP-IPv4 traffic from 192.168.0.0/22.

The connection between VPC A and VPC C is not working. I'm new to AWS and can't understand why its failing. Can anyone tell what I did wrong? Any help is accepted :)

Comment: Does the connection between VPC B and VPC C work?

Comment: You should add specific details of your failing test e.g. ping from 192.168.0.10 to 10.1.0.15 times out, and include traceroute/mtr. Also be aware of [VPC Reachability Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html).